# Network acting crazy... How can I know whether it's hardware?

Tags: debian, networking, hardware, network-interface

I have a homeserver, with a built-in network card, ASRock E350M1 Motherboard. On the computer there's a Debian Jessie system on an SSD, and 4 HDDs in raid configuration for my data. I usually have access through SSH to that computer. I don't need physical access to it, unless there's a problem.

Recently I started having problems with my network. Sometimes the computer boots, but I can't have SSH access to it. It takes a VERY long time to connect to my network. This doesn't happen always though! Yesterday I spend over 2 hours trying to get it to connect to my network, but it wouldn't work! pinging my router gave `network is unreachable`. Then suddenly it worked again!

So, I hooked my screen and keyboard there, and started investigating. While the network fails:

- My network hardware (eth0) uses hotplug and DHCP to find my network. This is default Debian behavior.
- The command `cat /etc/resolv.conf` returns the IP of my router (192.168.1.1).
- The command `ifconfig -a`, returns only IPv6 IPs. No IPv4!
- The command `route -n`, returns a wrong IP address that has nothing to do with my subnet (169.254.0.0)
- Trying to add my router gateway (`sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1`) fails with "SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable".
- No firewall is set at all!
- Network card information; the command `lspci | grep -i eth` returns: `09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd, RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)`
- Non-free firmware is already installed.

This thing is driving me crazy! What would you do? How can I know whether it's a hardware or software issue?

Comment: where is your DHCP server?  your router/modem? is it configured correctly?  on another tack, what kind of network card is in your linux PC? show output of `lspci | grep -i eth`.  Does it require non-free firmware?  if so, do you have it installed? (e.g. many Realtek NICs require the `firmware-realtek` package to be installed)

Comment: btw, the 169.254 address is a Link-Local Address.  It's not a problem in itself, it just indicates that the interface is not properly configured yet (e.g. hasn't yet received and accepted a DHCP offer).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

Comment: @cas Thanks for the info. The DHCP server is in my router and it doesn't have a problem as I have 5 other computers and smartphones at home that don't have a problem. The non-free firmware is already installed. I'll print the `lspci` output in the question now.

Comment: Are the IPv6 addresses you see global unicast, link-local, or something else?

Comment: @kasperd The IPv6 Addresses I see are Scope:Global, and Scope:Link.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist What are the first few characters of the Scope:Global address?

Comment: @kasperd 2003:75:... and fd58:6cb0:...

Comment: Try switching to a static ip configuration, as that may help you narrow it down to a hardware or a dhcp software problem.

Comment: @user1663987 Good idea! I'm testing that now, and it looks good. It works, but since it's a random problem I can't judge that the problem is solved. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try using the static ip for a while, if you can, and if the random problem does not seem to occur, then I would suggest uninstalling and purging the dchp client software and reconfiguring it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output of `dmesg` if there is a hardware/driver/frimware issue you should find some hints (wanings/errors) there.

And you could try booting from a live-CD (or USB) like https://www.debian.org/CD/live/.
If that works fine ist a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mii-tool` or `ethtool` on the interface to see whether Linux can tell that the ethernet card is working, and how that card is connected (speed, full or half-duplex, etc). Also, check the cabling. (re)Seat all plugs. Look at the connection lights on router and the ethernet cards.  They the cable on another computer if you can.